# Scraping specified links with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrap this site tribune.com.pk I wanted to collect the links of current trends showing on this website
    
            
        **Trending:**
        FIFAWorldcup2014ZarbeAzbAfghanElections2014musharrafpolioTahirulQadri

This is the source code of site which I am trying to scrap. I want to get the links of current trends. How can I retrieve these current trends with BeautifulSoup and Python.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

url = raw_input("Enter a website to extract the URL's from: ")

r  = requests.get(url)

data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for link in soup.findAll("a"):
 print(link.get('href'))
```

This above code returns me all the links of the site. How can I make it more specific ?

Comment: How exactly is this question any better than [your previous effort](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24726294/3001761)? Please read the material in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: What site are you trying to scrape? We have no idea.. Please be clear and informative.

Comment: I am trying to scrap this site tribune.com.pk I wanted to collect the links of current trends showing on this website @aIKid

Comment: have a look at using xpath:s for that div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to interpret "collect the links of current trends" as meaning "all the 'a' tags that are inside the div tag which has id=trendingbox"

You can use beautiful soup to select tags [using a CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)

Try changing your code to:

```
for link in soup.select("#trendingbox > a"):
    print link.get('href')
```

Comment: The snippet you gave is perfectly fine but it is quite different from the standard ways.I am now trying to extract the tags from any CSS class using standard methods listed in the link you provided but it isn't working. Will you help me in this regard ? @Jeremy Allen